# How to sort values in column to match with another column VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

List item

Hi I'm trying to figure out how I can sort column B in the order where the values in it matches with that of column A and delete the values in column B that are not in column A. Also I'd like to leave the cells empty in column B when the values does not match with that of column A. Can someone help me with the codes please? Thanks!!!

A     132 43 345 35 654 84 26 54 635

B     132 43 24 345 67  35 84 26  79 54

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to compare each row in column A and B, open new column c and enter for the first line:

```
=if(a1=b1,a1,””)
```

Drag it down .this should be your fixed column B. you can paste special values (instead of formulas) and erase the true column B afterwards.
If values are unique for each column and you want to make sure that a value in column a is found on column B with no rows relation:
Open a new C and enter on C1:

```
=ifna(vlookup(a1,b:b,1,0),””)
```

Same goes for here with drag, paste and erase.